# Sharepoint List - Calculated Column with commas

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have two Columns with **numbers separated by commas in a Sharepoint List.**  I want the result to be calculated in a new column:

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG4qJ.jpg)

So the result should be calculated used this logic:

**(10x10) + (2x5) + (6x3)**

Now there can be **many comma separated values** but values in **Values** col and **Stock** col will always have the same number of commas.  So the **formula should be smart enough to count number of commas** and multiple value in right order.

Any help is much appreciated. I am new to Sharepoint List so please try to break it down.

Thanks a lot in advance.